# JAVA No actualiza ni inserta datos en Mysql remoto

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos Mysql en un servidor, y tengo una aplicación en Java de escritorio.
Al usar la conexión local, funciona todo sin problemas, pero al hacer la conexión a la base de datos del servidor remoto, solo puedo ver los datos pero no puedo registrar, actualizar e insertar datos.
Erroe al registrar cliente com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 21.519 milliseconds ago.

Este es mi archivo de conexión:

```
package clientes_crud;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import static clientes_crud.conexion.con;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class conexion {
    
    // Declaramos la conexión a mysql
    public static Connection con;
    
    // Declaramos los datos de conexión a la bd
    // *Conectar MySQL al servidor remoto* //
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String bd = "nombre_DB";
    private static final String user = "Usuario";
    private static final String pass = "Password";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/"+bd;
    
    // Función que va a conectarse a la bd de mysql
    public Connection conectar(){
        con = null;
        try {
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            if(con != null){  
                System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
            }       
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error no se pudo conectar a la base de datos " );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Por favor me pueden ayudar, gracias de antemano

Comment: Prueba con `"jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/"+bd+"?autoReconnect=true";`

Comment: Hice lo recomendado, y no resultó, todo sigue igual, se conecta a la base de datos, muestra los registros pero no se puede modificar, ingresar ni eliminar registros